# implement Single sign on in CakePHP project

Tags: cakephp

I want to implement SSO in a CakePHP project. I will used cookies for doing this.

someone advised me to check CakePHP as there is a property that let you share session in different application using sessions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do this, I go to manage this using cookies, with native coding, as All projects share the same domain.

I make different kind of cookies which save:

1. Key
2. Security Hash
3. User Data Encrypted
4. save user last session into database to check on it
5. Back up server for login, because if the main server down no one can login,
6. Enable single application login in case two server are down or inaccessible.

With Some Flows, And ideas I make a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

[This article](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/view/how-to-bend-cakephp-s-session-handling-to-your-needs) might be able to help you.  I have to admit that I've not had much luck in the past getting CakePHP to play nicely with another framework.  [The alternative](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/view/using-cake-sessions-outside-of-cake) is to require the other application to use CakePHP's sessions, which is typically easier if it's not itself a framework.  If both are frameworks, I would recommend the first link.

Comment: +1 for the first link. Cake sessions outside cake are not that successful as you already suggested.